# Problems with KeyListener and JOGL

Tags: input, 2d, keylistener, jogl, translate-animation

I'm trying to bind a key to translate a GL_QUAD around the screen.  I created a class, as I will attach below, that implements KeyListener, and within that I have a method that upon the keypress of 'd', adds 0.1 to the x coordinates of the quad vertices.  Now, I have two questions relating to this.

1. Firstly, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Upon the keypress, nothing happens to the object.
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?  My end goal is to eventually end up with a sprite, that the camera is focused upon, that can move around a visually 2D game world.

Thanks for your time.

Code:

SpriteTest.java

```
package com.mangostudios.spritetest;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class SpriteTest 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        Frame frame = new Frame("AWT Window Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        canvas.addGLEventListener(new Renderer());

        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
        //animator.add(canvas);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Renderer.java

```
package com.mangostudios.spritetest;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;

public class Renderer implements GLEventListener {
    InputListener input = new InputListener();

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        update();
        render(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    }

    private void update() {
    }

    private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        // draw a triangle filling the window
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glVertex2f( input.xTran, 0.1f);
        gl.glVertex2f( input.xTran,-0.1f); 
        gl.glVertex2f( -input.xTran, -0.1f);
        gl.glVertex2f( -input.xTran, 0.1f);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
}
```

InputListener.java

```
package com.mangostudios.spritetest;

import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener;

public class InputListener implements KeyListener{
    boolean loopBool = false;
    float xTran = 0.1f;
    float yTran = 0.1f;
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent d) {
        loopBool = true;
        while (loopBool = true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent d) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you never call addKeyListener(). Secondly, you shouldn't put an infinite loop into keyPressed(). Thirdly, you use a NEWT KeyListener whereas you use an AWT GLCanvas :s Rather use GLWindow with a NEWT KeyListener or use an AWT GLCanvas with an AWT KeyListener or use NewtCanvasAWT. Finally, before writing your own example, try [mine on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL#Code_example) in order to understand why it works.